# Access modifier for default constructor in LINQ2SQL generated classes

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Just beginning with LINQ2SQL here and I have a few questions.

I have db with a single table Customer, I run sqlmetal and it generates an ORM class for me.

I'd like to apply certain rules in the constructor of Customer, maybe something like the 
firstName, lastName members of Customer have to be supplied.

I created a new constructor in the sqlmetal generated Customer class to
take 2 parameters firstName, secondName and then marked the default parameterless
constructor as internal as I don't want to expose that to whatever consumes this
assembly.

My code began to complain when I tried  to SubmitChanges() because of the new protection level of the parameterless constructor from public to internal.

```
List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>();
customerList = dbInstance.Customer.ToList();
Customer customerToDelete = customerList.Where(c => c.Customer_id == 100).First();
dbInstance.Customer.DeleteOnSubmit(customerToDelete);
dbInstance.SubmitChanges(); <-- error thrown
```

"No parameterless constructor defined for this object"

Why must the access modifier be public on the default constructor in the Customer ORM class? When it is public this works as expected.

Comment: Interestingly, I wouldn't be amazed if it needed that to *materialise* the objects. It is oddthat it needs then to *submit* them.

Answer (score 0):

LinqToSql generates partial classes, so you can use that. Also do not edit generated files. You will lose all changes after updating model.

Comment: Well having business logic in another Customer class marked partial will allow for i) the separation of business/data logic and ii) allow for the data layer to be rebuilt without losing any business data. So I take your point, but what if you want to hide a parameterless constructor or change the access modifiers on some of the properties that the partial ORM class exposes?